# C# - Extend/Add interface to parameter of overridden method

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, polymorphism, code-injection

I am pretty new to C#. I am trying to derive a class `UIObjectContainer : UIObject` which overrides a method `FillProperties` which 'fills' in a parameter `Properties` (just holds misc data).

I want to extend this parameter in the derived class to 'de-clutter' the base class and allow `Properties` instances to only contain necessary properties instead of all possible ones.

In my current usage, I simply stash several variables inside `Properties` and then access them in the derived class. Each null property still consumes 4-8 bytes depending on the system, compared to a Dictionary of properties which requires 20 bytes per property just having null properties seems preferable for my scenario.

This is a simplification of my current code:

```
public class Properties 
{
    public Color basePropertyColor;
    public List<Color> containerPropertyItemColors;
}

public class UIObject 
{
    public virtual void FillProperties(Properties properties) 
    {
        properties.basePropertyColor = Color.grey;
    }
}

public class UIObjectContainer : UIObject 
{
    public override void FillProperties(Properties properties) 
    {
        properties.containerPropertyItemColors = new List<Color>() { Color.red };
        base.FillProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

The drawback of this code is that `Properties` consumes unnecessary memory and contains several parameters which are grouped together in what seems like should be an interface on top of `Properties`.

Ideally this interface (or derived class) would be injected into the properties at runtime depending on what class we are in and which requirements it has. The interface design pattern here seems promising since it allows you to later check if `Properties` is of a certain type and do misc logic on the properties using the `is` keyword.

I tried the following but it seems like while this does not cause compilation errors it does not work as intended.

```
public class Properties 
{
    public Color basePropertyColor;
}

public class UIObject 
{
    public virtual void FillProperties(Properties properties) 
    {
        properties.basePropertyColor = Color.grey;
    }
}

public class PropertiesContainer : Properties, PropertiesWithMultipleItems 
{
    public float containerPropertyItemColors { get { return new List<Color>() { Color.red } }; }
}

public interface PropertiesWithMultipleItems 
{
    public List<Color> containerPropertyItemColors { get; }
}

public class UIObjectContainer : UIObject 
{
    public override void FillProperties(Properties properties) 
    {
        properties = new PropertiesContainer();
        properties.containerPropertyItemColors = 1;
        base.FillProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

Could someone take a look at the desired implementation and let me know what design pattern `Properties` needs to adapt in order to be extensible at runtime in the desired way?

Extension methods: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods, are promising but seem to suffer from the same interface/grouping problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a place where generics could be useful; since you could specify the property type as a generic parameter:

```
public class Properties {
    public Color basePropertyColor {get; set;}
}
public class UIObject<TProperties> where TProperties : Properties {
    public virtual void FillProperties(TProperties properties) {
        properties.basePropertyColor = Color.grey;
    }
}

public class PropertiesContainer : Properties {
    public float containerPropertyItemColors {get; set;}
}
public class UIObjectContainer : UIObject<PropertiesContainer> {
    public override void FillProperties(PropertiesContainer properties) {
        properties = new PropertiesContainer();
        properties.containerPropertyItemColors = 1;
        base.FillProperties(properties);
    }
}
```

Personally I would change `FillProperties` to return the `PropertiesContainer` instead of mutating your class state just to keep things cleaner as well. That would allow you to do `UIObject` as a template pattern to enforce that the derived `FillProperties` method exists and is called as well.

Answer (score 0):

In your example code at the very end, this line is completely obliterating what is being passed in: `properties = new PropertiesContainer();`

You should maybe change your last class to something like:

```
public class UIObjectContainer : UIObject {
    public override void FillProperties(Properties properties) {
        if (properties is not PropertiesContainer)
        {
            properties = new PropertiesContainer() { basePropertyColor = properties.basePropertyColor };
        }
        var container = properties as PropertiesContainer;
        container.containerPropertyItemColors = 1;
        base.FillProperties(container);
    }
}
```

This is just a rough example. But basically, if properties is not the correct derived type you need to create new derived type object and clone / copy in the values from the original object. Your current code just obliterates the original the object that is passed in and creates a brand new empty object of the derived type.

Another alternative would be something:

```
public class UIObjectContainer : UIObject {
    public override void FillProperties(Properties properties) {
        if (properties is not PropertiesContainer)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }
        var container = properties as PropertiesContainer;
        container.containerPropertyItemColors = 1;
        base.FillProperties(container);
    }
}
```

Basically throw an exception if you don't get the expected derived type. InvalidOperationException is just an example exception. You could make a custom exception to throw, or there might be a more appropriate pre-existing exception to throw that is logical to your api.